# background-image:url button broke in Chrome

Tags: html, css

My buttons work just fine in IE 9, Firfox 8.0.1 but in Chrome that is recent but not today's (I say this because I just downloaded and tested Chrome and it works fine) or IE8.

```
.descbutton
{
   background-image:url('../images8/arrow-down4.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   float:right;
   border:none;
}
```

My QA broke my buttons and I don't have an idea how to fix this. They show a border; which they should not, and image was blank. After extensive search I ask you gals and gents for an assist please.

Also thought I should include the code this is nested inside.

```
.infoTable2  {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
}

<td width="120" class= "infoTable2">
```

Comment: dumb question, but in your html are you telling it to use the correct class?

Comment: any question is good Joe.  But the answer is yes.

Comment: I did try a <div class="wrapper"></div> and .wrapper{clear:both;} but will not know if it works until QA gets back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I got it sorted. Hopefully yours is the same case.

Check if there is anywhere that the button is inheriting the style attribute `appearance` or either of the specific variants `-webkit-appearance`, `-moz-appearance`.

I had `appearance:button;` and it prevented background images from displaying on my buttons.